# URL parameter starting zero is removed

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have the URL: `http://localhost:3000/homebrew/board?id=078262`

I use node to get the id parameter and store it into a variable. When the page gets loaded, I use the variable with EJS to pass it to the client.

The issue is that if an id starts with zero `0`, it gets removed.

**App.JS**

```
app.get('/homebrew/:homebrewType', (req, res) => {

  var type = req.params.homebrewType;
  var homebrewId = req.query.id;

  console.log(homebrewId); // shows 078262
  console.log(typeof homebrewId); // string

...

  res.render('pages/homebrew-' + type, {
    homebrewId: homebrewId
  });
```

JS

```
var viewingHomebrew = <%= homebrewId %>;

console.log(viewingHomebrew); // shows 78262, starting 0 is missing
```

I don't have any other code, how can I preserve the id parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to make it a string instead of a number.

```js
var viewingHomebrew = "<%= homebrewId %>";
```